# SDK manager doesn't reload

Tags: android, sdk, windows-8

I recently installed the Android SDK on my Windows 8 PC (had it previously on Windows 7 too). Today, when checking for updates, I realised that it is not checking for updates at all. It only shows the packages I have already installed. I want to install some APIs but nothing shows up. Has anyone else got this problem? Is there a way to work around this and get it to update again?

Comment: How to migrate this question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Kaspersky blocking the Java exe's from running. Added exception and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem. Close Eclipse and open the SDK manager from the SDK folder directly. From there try and update.

Using that method I was able to get some updates but not all. I actually had to copy the missing SDK level (17 for me) from a flash drive to trigger the rest of the updates to show up for me.

**Edit**

After a few days of having the troubles not completely go away I simply delated the entire SDK folder and downloaded it again from Google.

So far everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: I am opening from the SDK folder only not from Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you had permission issue..

`try to run your sdk as administrator`

Comment: I don't think his answer was nonconstructive keeping in mind that the question didn't clarify the use of admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

### Problems connecting to the SDK repository

If you are using the Android SDK Manager to download packages and are encountering connection problems, try connecting over http, rather than https. To switch the protocol used by the Android SDK Manager, follow these steps:

With the Android SDK Manager window open, select "Settings" in the left pane.
On the right, in the "Misc" section, check the checkbox labeled "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."
Click Save & Apply.